# Data Transfer Through MVMM

Tags: ios, swift, oop, swiftui

I have a class like this.

```
class DeviceDetalis : ObservableObject {
    @Published var deviceName: String
    @Published var deviceID: String
    init(deviceName: String, deviceID: String) {
    self.deviceName = deviceName
    self.deviceID = deviceID
    }
}
```

And my .app file like this

```
var deviceInfo = DeviceDetalis(deviceName: "", deviceID: "")
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(deviceInfo)
    }
}
```

And one of my views using this object like this

```
    @EnvironmentObject var deviceDetails : DeviceDetalis
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Section {
                    TextField("Device name", text: $deviceDetails.deviceName)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    TextField("Deviceid", text: $deviceDetails.deviceID)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }
                .padding()
}
```

And the updated deviceDetails are using like this in other Struct

```
    @EnvironmentObject var deviceDetails : DeviceDetalis
    var body: some View {
            Section {
                        VStack(alignment : .leading) {
                            Text(deviceDetails.deviceName.uppercased())
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)                            
                                Text(deviceDetails.deviceID)
                                }
}
```

Upto This I have no Problem. but i want my another class to observe the changes done to deviceID property of DeviceDetails class

```
class fetchedData : ObservableObject {
lazy var urlString = "https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/Abhishektomar/feeds/\**(deviceID)**"
}
```

Basically the data entered by user in the view is updated in the DeviceDetails Class and i want to use that data in other class to call the url and load the data.I have no ides how to do this .

Comment: It depends on where `fetchedData` is created and used, but anyway it is better to call it directly and explicitly, ie. w/o tight coupling with DeviceDetalis.

Comment: This is a good case for Combine. Setup a publisher and subscriber. On a separate note, your environment object should be initialized as @StateObject

Answer (score 0):

You can use [task(id:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(id:priority:_:)) for that, the task is run whenever the id data changes, and it cancels a previous task if it changes while a task is still running, e.g.

```
Text(deviceDetails.deviceID)
.task(id: deviceDetails.deviceID) {
    do {
        self.results = await fetchData(deviceDetails.deviceID)
        self.message = "Success"
    catch {
        self.message = error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```